# Deep linking: id as host

Tags: android, android-manifest, deep-linking

I added this code in my Activity in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

  <data android:path="*" />
  <data android:scheme="schemetest" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then I have tested two deep links:

- schemetest://videos
- schemetest://**542325**

The first is working fine but the second one is not even considered.

When I modifiy it to: schemetest://**542325q** for example, it works.

So my question is: are numbers allowed as host?

Thanks a lot.